# Prove: for all $n$ there's a $m$ such that the sum of digits in $mn$ is equal to $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

In the following $n,m$ are natural numbers.

I need to prove that for all $n$ there's a $m$ such that the sum of digits in $mn$ is equal to $n$.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: Wish I had.. tried to see if there's a pattern in particular cases but nothing that i could generalized

Comment: I haven't worked anything out but this sounds like proof by contradiction might be worth a shot

Comment: Ok I'll try this idea thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is an infinite amount of  powers of $10$, however only a finite amount of congruence classes mod $m$, hence there must be at least one such congruence class containing an infinite amount of powers of $10$. Take $n$ distinct powers of ten in this congruence class. The sum of these numbers is a multiple of $n$ and the digits in the base $10$ representation of the sum  are all zeroes except for $n$ ones, thus the sum of the digits is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A proof is in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0477) of H. Fredricksen, E. J. Ionascu, F. Luca, and P. Stanica.  See also OEIS sequence [A131382](https://oeis.org/A131382).

Comment: Looks kind of advance for me,thanks!